# How to make sure file is created with the correct user or permissions?

Tags: java, bash, file, maven

The business model is a bit complex, so please forgive me if the explanation isn't 100% clear:

The Uploader interface (`String upload(String path, byte[] fileContents)`) defines different ways to upload a file (contained in the byte array), for example `AmazonUploader` which takes the content and the `path` string, and uploads it to Amazon S3 under the given key.

I have a class called `LocalUploader` which is used in QA, writes the given file array, as is, to the local disk.

The Uploader is used in two different cases:

1. The web interface, ran by user `web`
2. A command-line interface, ran by users logging into `ssh`, via user `root`.

The command-line interface is a different jar from the web interface, but they both have the Uploader bundled in. Also, the command-line executable is a bash script running `java -jar ....` at the end.

The idea is to save the files to a known location, and then serve them over a simple static http server.

**The problem in short**: Since both processes write to the same location, when a file is written by the command-line interface, it's no longer writable by the web interface (`web` can't access files made by `root`, obviously, no problems the other way around).

Now, I'm stuck with Java 6 for the Uploader, so no `nio` file package.

### Workflow in a nutshell:

[image: Workflow]

### Here's what I've tried:

- Use `java.io.File`'s `.setWritable()`. If I do it before writing the file, it fails (returns `false`), if I do it after, it returns true but doesn't set the `writable` flag.
- Use `su` to run the jar as another user. But that messes with the parameter insertion
- Use `umask`, was promptly ignored by Java. Probably because it's a different process.
- Use the group id flag for linux permissions - was promptly ignored by Java. Probably because it's a different process.

### What I didn't try:

- Use an ACL - We can't afford to mess with the underlying partitions.
- Return the file as output and have bash write the file - Not all commands need to write files, also, there may or may not be a need to write more than one file. This isn't logic I want to put in the bash script, that's the Uploader's job.

### Things to note:

- I am using Java 6 on the Uploader. No fancy stuff.
- I am using Spring 3.2 for the Uploader. No boot.
- I can *probably* use utility libraries in the Uploader.
- I am using Java **8** for the **command line executable**.

### Some relevant code:

#### Uploader.java

```
@Override
public String upload(String path, byte[] fileContents) {
    final File file = new File(path);
    try {
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, fileContents);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error writing file to path " + path, e);
    }
    return "";
}
```

#### init.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CONFIGDIR=${spring.config.location}
CONFIGFILE=$CONFIGDIR/${app.name}.conf
# Loading a settings from CONFIGFILE
[ -f $CONFIGFILE ] && source $CONFIGFILE

# Setting JAVA_BIN
if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
fi

# Starting the application
$JAVACMD $JAVA_OPTS -jar ${app.home}/bin/${build.finalName}.jar  "$@" --spring.config.location=$CONFIGDIR/
```

---

This whole thing smells like some trivial problem that shouldn't even be there in the first place, but I'm stumped. Would appreciate any help in the matter.

Comment: Parameter names in `bash` cannot contain periods. Is `init.sh` pre-processed by some other tool before being executed? (I ask because using `su`, or preferably `sudo`, is the probably the right answer. The jar file should be run as user "web" the same as in the web app, not as root.)

Comment: Yes, what you see are parameters which are substituted by Maven from pom.xml. The deployed version has environment specific paths there for the configuration directory.

Comment: what i did for a similar problem was using the `chmod` command like this. `String cmd[] = { "chmod", "644", file.getAbsolutePath() };`. Executing it afterwards as per Runtime `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` made the file writable and readable.

Comment: @chepner I disagreed with your edit and rollbacked. This has very little to do with maven, and a lot to do with files.

Comment: "nio" has got a method called setPosixFilePermissions -- it might help

Comment: @Madara, I am confident it's a yes, but you are using the 2 argument variant of setWritable() with `setWritable(true, false)` right?

Comment: @Codebender: I've tried both just in case. Both display the same behavior.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy: As I mentioned, I may not use `nio` as `Uploader` is both written in, and used by a project written in, Java 6.

Comment: It's at least somewhat relevant to Maven, as `init.sh` as shown is not valid `bash` code. It's possible that the correct way to run it using `su`/`sudo` involves Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using sudo?

```
sudo -u web $JAVACMD $JAVA_OPTS -jar ${app.home}/bin/${build.finalName}.jar  "$@" --spring.config.location=$CONFIGDIR/
```

This should work, since the command-line interface is invoked by users logged in as root (which is not recommendable, but I take it as given).

Comment: It is a given. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Maybe you have to fiddle a bit with the command-line argument passing, I cannot predict the behavior since I do not have your environment (feel free to post what happens). And if init.sh is not run as root, you may have to set the appropriate sudo-permissions in `sudoers`.